# Django contrib admin views limit customization

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm looking for a way to expose the pager limit as a form within admin views by adding a query argument such as `&?pager_limit=50` or something similar so it can merge happily with the various exposed filters.

I haven't really made any headway at all at solving the problem myself. I've been trawling through contrib.admin and contrib.users.admin and not able to find what I'm looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make `list_per_page` dynamic we need to subclass `ChangeList` since the default `ChangeList` class sets the `list_per_page` once.

For instance:

```
class CustomUserChangeList(ChangeList):
    def __init__(self, request, model, list_display, list_display_links,
                 list_filter, date_hierarchy, search_fields, list_select_related,
                 list_per_page, list_max_show_all, list_editable, model_admin):
        list_per_page = get_user_list_limit()
        super(CustomUserChangeList, self).__init__(request, model, list_display, list_display_links,
            list_filter, date_hierarchy, search_fields, list_select_related,
            list_per_page, list_max_show_all, list_editable, model_admin)
```

Then override `get_changelist` in the ModelAdmin subclass:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
        return CustomUserChangeList
```

Comment: >django 2.1:  add `sortable_by` to the arguments of `ChangeList.__init__`

Answer (score 1):

```
class ActionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_per_page = 25
```

You can specify it here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (kludgy) solution I came up with, based on [DanH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/698289/danh)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12852776/1091116):

1. Create a global function `return_changelist_for_request`, visible in `admin.py`:

   ```
   def return_changelist_for_request(request):
       class CustomUserChangeList(django.contrib.admin.views.main.ChangeList):
           def __init__(self, request, model, list_display, list_display_links,
                list_filter, date_hierarchy, search_fields, list_select_related,
                list_per_page, list_max_show_all, list_editable, model_admin):
                   try:
                       page_size = request.session.get('page_size', 100)
                       list_per_page = int(page_size)
                   except ValueError:
                       list_per_page = 100
                       request.session['page_size'] = list_per_page
                   super(CustomUserChangeList, self).__init__(request,
                       model, list_display, list_display_links, list_filter,
                       date_hierarchy, search_fields, list_select_related,
                       list_per_page, list_max_show_all, list_editable,
                       model_admin)
       return CustomUserChangeList
   ```
2. In the related ModelAdmin instances, add a call to this function, named `get_changelist` as in the example:

   ```
   class DeviceTypeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

       def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
           return return_changelist_for_request(request)

       list_display = ('devicetype', )
   ```
3. In `urls.py`, add a link to `page_size` view we'll add in a second:

   ```
   url(r'^page_size$', 'viewer.views.page_size', name='page_size'),
   ```
4. Add the view to `views.py`:

   ```
   from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

   def page_size(request):
       request.session['page_size'] = request.GET['page_size']
       return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
   ```
5. Copy Django admin's `base.html` template from site-packages to your template directory and add similar HTML code (this HTML example assumes [django-admin-bootstrapped](https://github.com/django-admin-bootstrapped/django-admin-bootstrapped)):

   ```
   <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action='/page_size'>
     <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Size" name="page_size" size="3">
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Set page size</button>
   </form>
   ```

(I added it before the closing `div` before `{% block object-tools %}{% endblock %}`)